# Are you entitled to a clean slate?

Tags: gezel-stealing

I remember reading somewhere that under Jewish law, someone convicted by a court and who has paid for his wrongdoing (fine, jail, restitution, whatever) is entitled to a clean slate and does not have to disclose, or be asked about, his past actions (such as by a prospective employer).  Is this so and what is the reference?

Comment: Good starting point: [Makot 12b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=25&daf=12b&format=pdf)

Comment: Are you asking about someone who has been convicted and punished by a Jewish court or a non-Jewish court?

Comment: @Robert Columbia  -- Either.